# My program keeps looping and I cannot figure out why

Tags: python-3.x

My program is continually looping and I would like to figure out why before I progress any further into the project it self. The programs purpose is to create a key from the alphabet that is used to decode/encode a message.

```
import random 
    def main():
        userselection = "0"
        print("This program allows you to create keys, econde plaintext, and decode ciphertext.")
        while userselection != "4":
            print("What would you like to do?")

        userselection = input("1.create a key 2.encode a message 3.decode a message 4.quit > ")
        if userselection == "1":
        #selection 1 stuffs goes here
            alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            key = ""
            letter = random.choice(alphabet)

        elif userselection == "2":
        #selection 2 stuffs 
            plaintext = plaintext.lower()
            ciphertext = ""
            for i in range(len(plaintext)):
                alphabetposition = alphabet.find(plaintext[i])

            if alphabetposition >= 0:
                ciphertext = ciphertext + key[alphabetposition]
            else:
                ciphertext = cipertext + plaintext[i]

        elif userselection == "3":
        #selection 3 stuffs
            print()

        elif userselection != "4":
            print("invalid selection")






    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: Shouldn't `userselection = input...` be indented another level? Otherwise you're just looping over the printout

Comment: The way this is written, you can never alter `userselection`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take user input inside the while loop. Try this :-

```
import random 
    def main():
        userselection = "0"
        print("This program allows you to create keys, econde plaintext, and decode ciphertext.")
        while userselection != "4":
            print("What would you like to do?")
            userselection = input("1.create a key 2.encode a message 3.decode a message 4.quit > ")
        if userselection == "1":
        #selection 1 stuffs goes here
            alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            key = ""
            letter = random.choice(alphabet)

        elif userselection == "2":
        #selection 2 stuffs 
            plaintext = plaintext.lower()
            ciphertext = ""
            for i in range(len(plaintext)):
                alphabetposition = alphabet.find(plaintext[i])

            if alphabetposition >= 0:
                ciphertext = ciphertext + key[alphabetposition]
            else:
                ciphertext = cipertext + plaintext[i]

        elif userselection == "3":
        #selection 3 stuffs
            print()

        elif userselection != "4":
            print("invalid selection")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

While loop at wrong position. It looping as you set userselection = "0" after that before user input you checking the 
while userselection != "4":
    print("What would you like to do?")

I will suggest you should comments this lines and take rerun.